# Calling one parameter from another parameter in String.AppendFormat

Tags: vb.net, string.format

I have a situation where I would have to do the following -

> String.Format("{0}",{1},"Hi!")

(This is just a very simple version of what i am trying to achieve)

And the output I want is -

Hi!

The output I am getting is -

{1}

String.Format("{0}","{1} Atul {2}","Hi!", "Kumar") I want the output to be - Hi Atul Kumar

Comment: @Steve That's what I thought at first, but it turns out it does compile - `{1}` is an array initialiser, the output is `"System.Int32[]"`.  Still doesn't match what the OP claims the output is though...

Answer (score 6):

`String.Format` is actually doing it's job perfectly. You pass `"{1}"` as the first format argument (I assume the `{1}` is within double quotes, or else the code won't produce the incorrect output you provided in your question). What you would instead want is to directly pass `"Hi"` as the first format argument:

```
String.Format("{0}, {1}", "Hi!", "<I think you want the user's name here>")
```

Seeing your comment below, you can use this:

```
String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", "Hi", "Atul", "Kumar");
```

Comment: String.Format("{0}","{1} Atul {2}","Hi!", "Kumar") I want the output to be - Hi Atul Kumar.

Comment: @nirajkasar To get what you want, refer to the second example provided in this answer.

Comment: I wanted to call one parameter from another parameter. Which I realized is not possible. Thanks anyways.